# How to write JPA query with multiple where clause

Tags: jpa

How to convert SQL query to JPA for below SQL query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM commodity comm, 
     configuration config, 
     customer customer 
where comm.commodity_id = config.commodity_id 
  and customer.customer_id = config.customer_id 
  and customer.customer_id=2 ;
```

I tried below but not working as expected,

```
@Query("SELECT commodity FROM Commodity commodity, SCConfig config, Customerdetails customer WHERE ( (commodity = config.commodity_id) and (customer = config.customer_id) and (config.customer_id = :customer_id) ) group by commodity)
```

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: you don't have "multiple where" clauses. You have two joins hidden in the where clause.

Comment: You are returning all fields from comm, config and customer in the SQL and in the JPQL you are returning only the entity comm (Commodity). What values do you like to be returned in the JPQL?

Comment: @Dherik, I want all the data from comm (Commodity).

Comment: Ok. How you map the entities and their relationships? Share your code here.

Comment: How to convert to JPQL ? JPQL relies on classes/fields and you present none.